# Can i use a Compaq Presario CQ60 Series Wireless LAN Card 459339-003 in a desktop computer with Windows 10 on it?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, desktop

I have a Compaq Presario CQ60 Series Wireless LAN Card 459339-003 that I am hoping to be able to put in my Desktop with Pentium dual core CPU E5800@ 3.2 GHz with 3 G of RAM, 64 bit op sys, x64zbased proc running Win10 Home ver. 21H1OS build 19043.1348 & Windows feature Exp. Pack 120.2212.3920.0 built by Geek Squad on 11/15/2020. For some reason I was given a ASUS USB AC-53 NANO USB Wireless Router and it is taking up a precious USB port

Comment: Hi Heidi, welcome. Valid question, but could you please elaborate a little bit? I'm not familiar with the hardware you're mentioning, but is that Compaq Card USB? PCIe? Something else altogether? Also, what exactly is it that you've tried but doesn't work?

Comment: It is a plug in card for a laptop and I am wondering g if it can go into a desktop.. both were built a year ago by the geek squad but the laptop wont start all of the way am not sure why so I tore it apart and kept a few things and was hoping I could free up my USB port by plugging this card inside. Not sure how to add pictures on here or if I even can so I can show what I'm talking about, but it you put the card name in Google it'll bring up the picture of it, my comp is a e-machine with everything I listed before

Comment: Yes, I forgot you probably can't post pictures because you don't have enough reputation. Can you try again? Also, please edit your post to make it a bit easier on the eyes :)